# On OpenCL, can we assume that consecutive writes are atomic?

Tags: opencl

Consider the following code in OpenCL:

```
void set_vals(__global int* mem) {
    mem[0] = 1;
    mem[1] = 2;
}

void get_vals(__global int* mem) {
    int x = mem[0];
    int y = mem[1];
    printf("%d %d\n", x, y);
}
```

Assuming that the memory starts all zeroes, and that two work-items run `set_vals` and `get_vals` in parallel, what are the possible values to be printed? Obviously, `0 0` and `1 2` are possible, but are `1 0` and `0 2` possible too? Mind also the following code:

```
void set_vals(__global int2* mem) {
    mem[0] = (int2)(1, 2);
}

void get_vals(__global int2* mem) {
    int2 a = mem[0];
    printf("%d %d\n", a.x, a.y);
}
```

What about that case: are `1 0` and `0 2` possible, or are vector writes atomic?